# Is there an alternative way to request JSON REST API in django?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I currently have a fully working Serializers using the Django REST Framework.
I want to be able to parse data or request data that can be used in my django app.
I have been using

```
import requests
r = requests.get('django_api_url')
data = json.loads(r.text)
```

I have no problem using this, but I'm trying to see if there's a better/faster way.
EDIT:
Basically looking for something to replace requests.get()

Comment: tommy, are you trying to access the data from within the app in the backend? could you provide more context on what you are trying to do that is requiring you to make requests to the REST API in python?

Comment: @RohanVarma yes that is exactly what I'm doing. I'm trying not to use the django query, but rather data that has been serialized.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to access the data in your backend, you can do this in a clean python file by simply importing your models and also import your serializers and then using them as your wish. For example:

```
from api_app.models import Model1, Model2
from api_app.serializers import ModelSerializer1, ModelSerializer2

def get_model1_instance():
    m1 = Model1.get(pk=1)
    m1_data = ModelSerializer1(m1).data
    print(m1_data)
```

The important thing to understand is that you cannot just run this python file. Since it is using django libraries and your django project code, it has to be run from the context of django. The way to do this would be to open the django shell with the command `python manage.py shell`, import the functions you want to run from the file, and then call the functions. When you import and run code in the django shell, it runs the files as though it was in the django app. For example:

```
$ python manage.py shell
> from access_api_data.py import get_model1_instance
> get_model1_instance()
...
```

If you want to call the functions that you write in this file within your backend in the actual web app, you can import the functions from the file into your views and call them and they should work.

Comment: Are there attributes that I can insert into `'m1'` of `ModelSerializer(m1).data` that will let me access specific objects without having to do `from api_app.models import Model1, Model2`?
Essentailly do a `Model1.objects.find(id=1)` but in `ModelSerializer()`?

Comment: I don't believe that is possible. Why are you trying to fit that constraint? Maybe if I know what you are trying to avoid, I can think of another workaround

Answer (score 0):

Try `data = r.json()` to remove the need for `json.loads(r.text)`

See the docs for [response.json](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content)